# DIH in SOLR based on primary key of a table

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

currently am using DIH for pulling data from MSSQL server to SOLR. Where in am using dataimporter.last_index_time to pull the records which are into database only after last_index_time. So i was exploring if there are any other option for DIH to use instead of using last_index_time may be something like last_pk_id. 
Is such option available?  could anyone let me know.

Comment: Its better to stick to the `dataimporter.last_index_time` as nothing can be more accurate in determining the data.

Comment: Problem is sometime due to seconds difference between the database and SOLR servers few documents are getting missed.

Comment: This might help - http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/dih-last-index-time-exacty-what-time-is-this-capturing-td499851.html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570742/solr-delta-import-handler-timestamp-not-specific-enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not provided by Solr itself.

But nothing prevents you from doing this:

1. set your DIH sql for the delta like this:
        WHERE (last_pk_id > '${dataimporter.request.LAST_PK_ID}')
2. when you run some indexing, store, outside Solr, the last_pk_id value you indexed, say 333.
3. next time you need to delta index, add to your request
       ...&clean=false&LAST_PK_ID=333
4. store your new LAST_PK_ID (you can query solr for this)